# Creating a hash / seed value from 2+ integers (fast)

Tags: c++, random, hash

I'm working on generating different types of Gradient Noise. One of the things that this noise requires is the generation of random vectors given a position vector.

This position vector could be anything from a single int, or a 2D position, 3D position, 4D position etc.

On top of this, an additional "seed" value is needed.

What's required is a hash of these n+1 integers into a unique integer with which I can seed a PRNG. It's important that it's these values as I need to be able to retrieve the original seed every time the same values are used.

So far I've tried an implementation of Fowler–Noll–Vo; but it was way too slow for my purposes.

I've also tried using successive calls to a pairing function:

```
int pairing_function(int x, int y)
{
    return(0.5*(x+y)*(x+y+1) + x);
}
```

I.e.:

```
int hash = pairing_function(pairing_function(x,y),seed);
```

But what seems to happen is that with a large enough seed, the values overflow the size of an int (or even larger types).

What's a good method to achieve what I'm trying to do here? What's important is speed over any cryptographic concerns as well as not returning numbers larger than my original data types.

I'm using C++ but so long as any code is readable I can nut it out.

Comment: Just simply XORing them all together would seem to satisfy your requirements.

Comment: I should have mentioned that the order is important as well. I.e. in the case of 2 or more dimensions (2,3) with a seed should return a different hash than (3,2) with the same seed.

Comment: Shift the intermediate result left before XORing each new number. Works as long as `n` is not too large (if it's greater than the number of bits in the hash, leftmost number will scroll off and not participate in the final value at all).

Comment: Hey thanks man, this worked out to do exactly what I needed. I would accept it as the answer, but it's just a comment. If you write out an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2):

It is strange that FNV be *way too slow* because it is just 1 xor and 1 integer product per byte of data. From [Wikipedia](http://www.isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/fnv/index.html) [it is ] *designed to be fast to compute*.

If you want something really quick, you can try these implementations, where the multiplication is coded as shifts and additions :

dan bernstein implementation :

```
unsigned long
hash(unsigned char *str)
{
    unsigned long hash = 5381;
    int c;

    while (c = *str++)
        hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c; /* hash * 33 + c */

    return hash;
}
```

sdbm implementation (hash(i) = hash(i - 1) * 65599 + str[i]) :

```
static unsigned long
sdbm(str)
unsigned char *str;
{
    unsigned long hash = 0;
    int c;

    while (c = *str++)
        hash = c + (hash << 6) + (hash << 16) - hash;

    return hash;
}
```

References ["Hash Functions" from cse.yorku.ca](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like FNV you used might have been inefficient because of the way it was used.  Here's (I think, I haven't tested it) the same thing in a way that could be trivially inlined.

```
inline uint32_t hash(uint32_t h, uint32_t x) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    h ^= x & 255;
    x >>= 8;
    h = (h << 24) + h * 0x193;
  }
  return h;
}
```

I think calling `hash(hash(2166136261, seed), x)` or `hash(hash(hash(2166136261, seed), x), y)` should give you the same result (assuming little-endian) as a library function.

However, to speed that up at the cost of hash quality, you can might try a change like this:

```
inline uint32_t hash(uint32_t h, uint32_t x) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    h ^= x & 65535;
    x >>= 16;
    h = (h << 24) + h * 0x193;
  }
  return h;
}
```

or even:

```
inline uint32_t hash(uint32_t h, uint32_t x) {
  h ^= x;
  h = (h << 24) + h * 0x193;
  return h;
}
```

These changes weaken the low-order bits somewhat, so you'll want to follow standard practice in using the high-order bits preferentially.  For example, if your need only 16 bits, then shift the final result right by 16 rather than masking it with `0xffff`;

The `h = ...` line will regularly overflow an int, though, and it relies on the standard mod-2**32 behaviour.  If that's a problem then you'll want to replace that line with something different and perhaps accept fewer useful bits in your hash.  Maybe `h = (h >> 4) + (h & 0x7fffff) * 0x193;` but that's just a random tweak and I haven't checked it for hash quality.

Answer (score 0):

I will challenge you on

> So far I've tried an implementation of Fowler–Noll–Vo; but it was way too slow for my purposes.

as in some simple benchmarks I've done the FNV hash is the fastest. I assume you have benchmarks for all hashes you've tried?

For the benchmark I just simply measured the time taken for 1 billion hashes of various algorithms in MVSC++ 2013 using two 32-bit `unsigned int` for input:

- **FNV (32-bit)** = 222M hashes/sec
- **Your `pairing_function()`** = 175M hashes/sec
- **Simple Hash `x + (y << 10)`** = 170M hashes/sec
- **Your `hash()` function using `pairing_function()`** = 167M hashes/sec
- **Dan Bernstein** = 101M hashes/sec

Obviously these are very basic benchmark results and I wouldn't necessarily trust them all that much. I wouldn't be surprised to see some algorithms run faster/slower on different platforms and compilers.

Overall though, while FNV is the fastest in this case there is only a factor of two difference between the fastest and slowest. If this really makes a difference in your case I would suggest taking another look at your problem to see if it can be redesigned to not need the hash or at least reduce the dependence on the hash speed.

**Note:** I changed your pairing function to:

```
int pairing_function(int x, int y)
{
    return((x+y)*(x+y+1)/2 + x);
}
```

for the above benchmarks. Using your version results in a conversion to/from `double` which makes it x5 slower and your `hash()` function x8 slower.

**Update**

For the FNV hash I found a [source online](http://www.isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/fnv/index.html) and modified it from there to work directly on 2 integers (assumes a 32-bit integer):

```
#define FNV_32_PRIME 16777619u

unsigned int FNVHash32(const int input1, const int input2)
{
    unsigned int hash = 2166136261u;
    const unsigned char* pBuf = (unsigned char *) &input1;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        hash *= FNV_32_PRIME;
        hash ^= *pBuf++;
    }

    pBuf = (unsigned char *) &input2;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        hash *= FNV_32_PRIME;
        hash ^= *pBuf++;
    }

    return hash;
}
```

Since FNV just works on bytes you can extend this to work with any number of integers or other data.

Comment: I used code from boost that uses strings rather than int. I needed this to prevent a 1d position of 3 and a seed of 43 from being the same as a position of 34 and a seed of 12.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. For most hash functions, including the FNV and DB used here, the hash output is different depending on the order of the data, i.e., `FNV(1, 2) != FNV(2, 1)`. If you're looking for a perfect hash algorithm with no collisions that is a completely different beast to tackle.

Comment: Just that the implementation of boost uses `string`s rather than `int`s and iterates through each byte. Can you point me to an FNV function that uses 2 inputs? Is it just XORing them together prior to hashing?

Comment: Added FNV code for 2 integers and source for the general FNV hash algorithm. If you are actually converting integers to strings to get your hash then that would explain why it is so slow for you. Just do the hashing on the raw data bytes to avoid the conversion.

Comment: FNV is slow because its per byte, there are other integer hashing options, mainly Murmur and Cityhashing which perform better, but do not work on arbitrarily sized data (which is exactly what OP needs).